# How to match branches with negative and positive lookahead regex?

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I'm working with some builds and have to write a regex **to include some branches, but exclude others** (in order to create the builds).

The best I could come up with **is this regex which uses positive and negative lookahead** to match the branch names:

```
(?=.*12\.3)^((?!(version-12\.3)).)*$
```

Here are the branch names and **how they should be matched**:

```
bugfix-ISSUE-123-some-details-version-12.3
ISSUE-1234-some-other-details-version-12.3
bugfix-12.3
bugfix2-12.3
12.3stuff
stu12.3ff

// match everything above, but don't match anything from below

master
version-12.3
version-3.21
some-other-branch
bugfix-3.21
test
```

Please use [**this online tool**](http://www.regexpal.com/94366) (it's the only one I found that **supports negative and positive lookahead regexes**).

Right now the regex I came up with **works fine, EXCEPT for the following 2 branches**:

```
bugfix-ISSUE-123-some-details-version-12.3
ISSUE-1234-some-other-details-version-12.3
```

The reason they are not included is because I used this negative lookahead regex which excludes `version-12.3` (what I want), but also excludes anything else that includes this string (like `ISSUE-123-version-12.3`, which I want included, but it's not):

```
((?!(version-12\.3)).)*$
```

**Can you help a bit, please?**

Comment: Hm, try [`^(?!version-\d.).*12\.3.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/tSMZJu/1). If the `version-<digit+.>` is disallowed as a *whole string*, use `(?!version-[\d.]+$)` instead of `(?!version-\d.)`.

Comment: Игорь, does it work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes, please submit an answer so I can vote and accept it! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to fail all matches where a string having `12.3` inside starts with `version-`+some digits/dots, you may use

```
^(?!version-\d+\.\d).*12\.3.*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tSMZJu/4).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!version-\d+\.\d)`  - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `version-`, 1+ digits, a dot and a digit right at the start of the string
- `.*`  - any 0+ chars (other than line break chars)
- `12\.3` - a `12.3` substring
- `.*`  - any 0+ chars (other than line break chars)
- `$` - end of string.

If the `version-` + digits/dots is disallowed as a *whole string*, use

```
^(?!version-[\d.]+$).*12\.3.*$
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tSMZJu/5).

Here, `^` will match the start of string and then the `(?!version-[\d.]+$)` will trigger the check: if there is `version-` followed with 1+ digits/dots up to the string end (`$`) the match will be failed.